# Executable binaries and the OS

Tags: executable, machine-code

I know that executable files (eg: .exe for Windows) are binaries. I know about hex files and assembly and so on. I also know about OS API's. Theoretically, I could write a web browser entirely in assembly code that uses the OS API's, assemble it with NASM and get an executable. But my question is, how do operating systems control the applications? For example, I could have a executable on Windows that writes to the video memory, and fills the screen with random stuff. I've tried this (actually) and Windows halts the application. How does it control the application? Moreover, if I have a linux executable and I attempt to run it on a Windows machine with the exact same hardware, theoretically, it should work (though it won't use any Windows API's) since the processor architecture is the same, but yet It cant. How exactly does the OS 'control' the binaries?

Answer (score 0):

The operating system, in particular windows and linux protect other applications and the operating system itself from applications.  So there is a protection layer that an application ideally cannot punch through running as a user.

You want to put pixels on the screen, you have to ask the operating system to do it for you.  If the operating system allows a way to punch through (calling mmap perhaps having to run as root) then you can trash the computer at will, yes.  The plan/design is to not let you have direct access, you are given a virtual space, a sandbox, for your application to play in, you have a virtual address space with some ram you can read and write at will, but you go outside that, you need to be shut down or at least handled in some way.

As far as what language you write applications in yes, if it is a normal windows program or linux program, then anything you can do to generate machine code for that target, asm, ada, C, etc.  If you are talking specific virtual machines (java, python) then your choices get more limited.  If you want to do more than play in your space, like have some sort of output other than a return value, then you have to make system calls in the way that the system requires them, which is target and operating system specific.  And again, you get the right instructions or registers or memory structure or whatever is required by the operating system for that call in whatever language you are using or libraries you can link with then the rest of your program can be in whatever language, yes absolutely you want to write a web browser in assembly language using nasm, completely doable.  have to create a binary format the os supports, and make the system calls as needed in the way that the system requires.